# ValueError: Expected input batch_size (16) to match target batch_size (64)

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I am going to implement 2-D convolution function from scratch without using PyTorch built-in convolution functions,TensorFlow, or other neural network packages.

After run the code
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (16) to match target batch_size (64).
occur.

Please find why and let me know the parts to be modified.

```
This is my code.

###
# Question (e)
# Train your ConvNet to achieve test accuracy above 70%
# You can try or add other training options such as SGD or callbacks to schedule learning rates if you want.
###

class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    """
    Builds a ConvNet model.

    Question (e)
    - things that might be useful...
    - stack [Conv2D + Conv2D + MaxPool2D] at least three times,
    - follwed by at least three Linear layers.
    - 3x3 filter is enough, but feel free to use larger filter size.
    - channels used: [10, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
    - you can choose smaller or larger channel size as well.
    - The model may include BatchNormalization, regularizers, and Dropout, but they are not necessary.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Define the layers that you would like to use in your model.
        """
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()

        ##### YOUR CODE #####
        # Convolutional layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, padding=1)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3, padding=1)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, padding=1)

        # Batch Normalization
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256)

        # Dropout
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)

        # Fully connected layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256 * 4 * 4, 1024)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512, 10)  # Assuming 10 classes in CIFAR-10
        #####################

    def forward(self, x):
        """
        Apply forward pass of the given batch of input images.
        Inputs
        - x: batch of input images.
        Returns
        - scores of input images for each class label
        """

        ##### YOUR CODE #####
        # Apply Convolutional layers + ReLU + MaxPooling
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv2(x))))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.bn2(self.conv4(x))))

        # Flatten the output for the fully connected layers
        x = x.view(-1, 256 * 4 * 4)

        # Apply Fully connected layers + ReLU
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        #####################

        return x

"""
Make sure your runtime type is GPU and you are using PyTorch version higher than 1.8!

Do NOT modify.
"""

DEVICE = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available else torch.device('cpu')
print("Using PyTorch version: {}, Device: {}".format(torch.__version__, DEVICE))

"""
Load your customized model "ConvNet" and its training settings.
You may choose the number of epochs that you would like to train.
You might want to use different optimizers or learning rates.
"""

EPOCHS = 20
model = ConvNet().to(DEVICE)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=1e-4)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

print(model)

"""
Train your model "ConvNet" with the augmented CIFAR-10 dataset.
Upon successful training, test accuracy of your model should be above 70%.

Do NOT modify.
"""

for epoch in range(1, EPOCHS + 1):
    train(model, train_loader, optimizer)
    test_loss, test_accuracy, test_f1_score = evaluate(model, test_loader)
    print("\n[EPOCH: {}], \tModel: ConvNet, \tTest Loss: {:.4f}, \tTest Accuracy: {:.2f}, \tTest F1_Score: {:.4f} % \n".format(
        epoch, test_loss, test_accuracy, test_f1_score))
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).